# NoSuchMethodError when developing Jenkins plugin with Spring Social Framework

Tags: java, spring, maven, spring-mvc, jenkins

I am working on a Jenkins plugin using the Spring Framework, and am running into this error when I run the plugin:

```
java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.springframework.util.CollectionUtils.unmodifiableMultiValueMap(Lorg/springframework/util/MultiValueMap;)Lorg/springframework/util/MultiValueMap;
at org.springframework.web.util.HierarchicalUriComponents.<init>(HierarchicalUriComponents.java:84)
at org.springframework.web.util.UriComponentsBuilder.build(UriComponentsBuilder.java:364)
at org.springframework.web.util.UriComponentsBuilder.build(UriComponentsBuilder.java:348)
at org.springframework.web.util.UriTemplate.<init>(UriTemplate.java:69)
at org.springframework.web.client.RestTemplate.execute(RestTemplate.java:531)
at org.springframework.web.client.RestTemplate.postForObject(RestTemplate.java:332)
at org.springframework.social.oauth2.OAuth2Template.postForAccessGrant(OAuth2Template.java:242)
at org.springframework.social.oauth2.OAuth2Template.exchangeForAccess(OAuth2Template.java:144)
at ain.tolva.updates.FBUpdater.<init>(FBUpdater.java:48)
at ain.tolva.FBNotifier.perform(FBNotifier.java:38)
at hudson.tasks.BuildStepMonitor$3.perform(BuildStepMonitor.java:45)
at hudson.model.AbstractBuild$AbstractBuildExecution.perform(AbstractBuild.java:785)
at hudson.model.AbstractBuild$AbstractBuildExecution.performAllBuildSteps(AbstractBuild.java:726)
at hudson.maven.MavenModuleSetBuild$MavenModuleSetBuildExecution.post2(MavenModuleSetBuild.java:1037)
at hudson.model.AbstractBuild$AbstractBuildExecution.post(AbstractBuild.java:671)
at hudson.model.Run.execute(Run.java:1766)
at hudson.maven.MavenModuleSetBuild.run(MavenModuleSetBuild.java:529)
at hudson.model.ResourceController.execute(ResourceController.java:98)
at hudson.model.Executor.run(Executor.java:408)
```

After researching, I came to conclude that somehow I am unable to get a recent enough version of spring, despite specifying a version of the spring framework that has the method in question (Maven):

```
<dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-core</artifactId>
        <version>4.3.2.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>

    <!-- Spring Social -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.social</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-social-core</artifactId>
        <version>1.1.4.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-security-web</artifactId>
        <version>4.1.3.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>

    <!-- Spring Social Facebook -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.social</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-social-facebook</artifactId>
        <version>2.0.3.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>
```

I have also tried this with the LATEST version of each, as well as a few other ways.

My next idea was to try to add the latest Spring io platform as stated [here](http://platform.spring.io/platform/), which cleared the error, but also threw up this one while building:

```
SEVERE: Failed Inspecting plugin C:\[REDACTED]\JenFacebook\work\plugins\Facebook.hpl
java.util.zip.ZipException: error in opening zip file
at java.util.zip.ZipFile.open(Native Method)
at java.util.zip.ZipFile.<init>(ZipFile.java:219)
at java.util.zip.ZipFile.<init>(ZipFile.java:149)
at java.util.jar.JarFile.<init>(JarFile.java:166)
at java.util.jar.JarFile.<init>(JarFile.java:130)
at jenkins.util.AntClassLoader.addPathFile(AntClassLoader.java:502)
at hudson.ClassicPluginStrategy$AntClassLoader2.addPathFiles(ClassicPluginStrategy.java:768)
at hudson.ClassicPluginStrategy.createClassLoader(ClassicPluginStrategy.java:278)
at hudson.ClassicPluginStrategy.createPluginWrapper(ClassicPluginStrategy.java:253)
at hudson.PluginManager$1$3$1.run(PluginManager.java:254)
at org.jvnet.hudson.reactor.TaskGraphBuilder$TaskImpl.run(TaskGraphBuilder.java:169)
at org.jvnet.hudson.reactor.Reactor.runTask(Reactor.java:282)
at jenkins.model.Jenkins$7.runTask(Jenkins.java:905)
at org.jvnet.hudson.reactor.Reactor$2.run(Reactor.java:210)
at org.jvnet.hudson.reactor.Reactor$Node.run(Reactor.java:117)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
```

I'm really not sure what I am missing, and can't find anything that can point me in the right direction yet.

Answer (score 0):

**CollectionUtils.unmodifiableMultiValueMap was added in Spring 3.1** but does not appear in earlier versions. **Looks like you are building application using spring-core 3.1, but your runtime environment is using an older version.**

Perhaps you upgraded Spring recently and have a stale lib directory somewhere that includes multiple versions of spring-core? As per my understanding Java always seems to pick the wrong one (older) and I get errors like these. Ensure thay you do not have spring-core 3.0 or earlier anywhere in your environment

Now since you upgraded spring to latest version our error is resolved.

New execption you are getting since some jar is corrupted.
Make sure your jar file is not corrupted. If it's corrupted or not able to unzip, this error will occur.

You can follow below steps:

**Step1**

Clean your .m2\repository or delete your specific folders from the .m2\repository directory

**step2**.

run mvn clean install -U

**step3**.

your internet connection must be working fine at the time of running this command, some times it fails due to connection problems.